# how to get value of data-url of a specific div with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get a value of an attribute of a specific div how to do it.

```
<div id="syllabus-stages" data-featurette="async-element" data-url="/library/aspnet-mvc-forms/stages" data-strategy="update"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show what you have you tried ?

Comment: @shekhar,I just want extract value of data-url please help me

Comment: why give me negative point?

Comment: Go through this https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Comment: "I want" is not a "show any research" - so post will get downvotes for lack of *demonstrated research" like searching for [c# htmlagilitypack element by id](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20htmlagilitypack%20element%20by%20id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you will use the HTML parser HtmlAgilityPack (you have the tag in your question):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.mywebsite/mypage");

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(downloadString);
//string whatUrLookingFor = doc.GetElementbyId("syllabus-stages").InnerHtml;
string whatUrLookingFor = doc.GetElementbyId("syllabus-stages").Attributes["data-url"].Value;
```